# add onclick event on table created by js using append and navigate to show relevant data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have created 1 table on html using data from an array. Now what i want is a user to click on the names showing in the table [page name -showlist.html] and then on the next page it should show the description inside a div. How can i achieve it, Please note - the data which i am fetching in an array is from local storage]

Please see my code below, i repeat-
1. Need to add a click on `array_no.title` and then navigation to a new page and
2. show `<div id="showData"> description of this title </div>` , below also attaching reference of the array structure for better understanding
[image]

```
function fetch_section_data_1(){

var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
  return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
});

var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
});
console.log(dataArray.length);

var $table = $( "<table></table>" );
for(i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
    var array_no = dataArray[i];
    var $line = $( "<tr></tr>" );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( array_no.title ) );
    $table.append( $line );

}

$table.appendTo(document.body);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an click event to your table row. Something like this:

```
function fetch_section_data_1(){
  var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
    return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
  });

  var dataArray = [{
    title: "test1",
    description: "<h1>test1</h1>"
  },
  {
    title: "test2",
    description: "<h1>test2</h1>"
  }]
  console.log(dataArray.length);

  var $table = $( "<table></table>" );
  for(i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
      var array_no = dataArray[i];
      var $line = $( "<tr class='row'></tr>" );
      $line.click(function(event) {
        var index = $(this).index();
        var item = dataArray[index];
        $("#description").html(item.description);
      })
      $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( array_no.title ) );
      $table.append( $line );

  }

  $table.appendTo(document.body);

  var descriptionContainer = $("<div id='description'>yes</div>'");
  descriptionContainer.appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle where it works. I just created a temp array of data:
https://jsfiddle.net/jpn3bqst/

Comment: when i click any title no which which, it shows me last object's description  and not it's relevant description, i have recorded a video to show you `http://youtu.be/ZyeFbW8o-tY?hd=1`

Comment: sorry i was a bit to fast. Changed the code so it picks the right object on click. I will add a jsfiddle where it works as well.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, This page is `showlist.html` , when i click on showlist.html, i want to load this data on showdescription.html inside a div, can you guide me how to achieve that.